# Manually cleaning up a threat detected by Sophos Anti-virus?

Tags: anti-virus, virus

I was viewing [another answer on this website](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389/218) and one of the links lead me to a malicious website. I have [Sophos Antivirus](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/) installed, and a warning immediately popped up telling me that a threat was detected:

> **Threat**: [Mal/Badsrc-M](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware/Mal~Badsrc-M.aspx)
>   **Path and Filename**: /Users/USER/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache/f_000e36
>   **Action Available**: The threat cannot be cleaned up. Please click the threat name above for manual cleanup instructions.

On the website, there are no instructions as to how to cleanup the threat. Even though this seems to be only a Windows virus, I still want it removed on my Mac so that it can't infect any other computers. Is it as simple as manually deleting the file listed above, or is there anything else I need to be worried about?

Comment: The greater threat to your Mac is Sophos Antivirus. A windows program cannot run under OSX and so poses no threat.

Answer (score 1):

Minus the fact that Sophos is just a giant waste of resources and space on your mac. The easiest way to clean it up would be to close chrome and go to that path in terminal and delete the file.

Open terminal and type the following:

```
rm -f /Users/USER/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache/f_000e36
```

That should delete the file forcibly.

Personal Note:

Having to run antivirus on your mac to protect windows machines is like wearing a helmet at your desk cause the guy on the bike outside might get hit by a car....

Comment: Your last sentence might look like an argument justifying to keep crapware on a Mac just because it doesn't risk anything immediatly.
I don't feel comfortable with such an argument and its consequences.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the steps Sophos wants you to take are found on [this page](http://www.sophos.com/support/knowledgebase/article/112129.html):

> 1. Open the Quarantine Manager.
> 2. [...]
> 3. If there are any threats for which the action available is 'Clean up manually', create a custom scan.
> 4. Select the areas where the remaining threats reside and add these to the Scan Items.
> 5. In the Options tab, select 'Delete threat' from the drop down menu.
> 6. Click Done.
> 7. Run the scan.

Tip: When choosing which folder to scan in step 4, I needed to navigate to the hidden `Library` folder in the Sophos dialog, which I couldn't do. So what I ended up doing was using Finder's `Go` > `Go To Folder...` menu option to first get to the folder, and then I created a shortcut to the cache folder in my `Documents` folder. Then when it asked me to select a folder to scan, I simply followed that shortcut I created.

Comment: When the Go menu is open, hold the option key. (Youre welcome.)

Comment: @Timothy: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, that feature doesn't work in the dialog that Sophos uses.

Comment: But you're in Finder, not a dialog box...

Comment: @Timothy: When you follow the steps outlined above, you're in a dialog box in step 4.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was replying to the "Tip:" at the end.

Comment: @Timothy: Oh I see the source of confusion, I'll try clarifying that part.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2832/discussion-between-senseful-and-timothy-mueller-harder)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your browsing data like [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?p=settings_clear_browsing_data&rd=1) if you must. It is in Google chrome cache buddy.

And then you find and remove:

- /Applications - any .app starting Sophos
- /Library/Application Support/Sophos - entire folder (SAV 9 only)
- /Library/Caches - all folders with com.sophos in name
- /Library/Contextual Menu Items/Sophos Anti-Virus.plugin (SAV 8 only)
- /Library/Extensions - all .kext files with Sophos in name
- /Library/Frameworks/SAVI.framework & SUMScanKit.framework
- /Library/LaunchAgents - all .plists with sophos in name
- /Library/LaunchDaemons - all com.sophos plists
- /Library/Sophos Anti-Virus - entire folder
- /Library/usr/bin/sweep N.B. /Library/usr folder is invisible in the Finder.